# video autoplayed on iOS devices

Tags: javascript, jquery, video, html5-video, autoplay

I have used video tag with autoplay attribute. I know that autoplay works if the video is muted and in my case there is no mute but, if I click on play button for first time as a gesture to play it, then after closing the video and again loading back, it does not required user gesture to play, it gets autoplayed.
Once a user gesture is used to play the video then from second time video starts to autoplay as its own without any gesture. I have not found any policy regarding the second time autoplay on iphone devices without user gesture on play button. 
Please help me to find the policy which describes a user gesture required for the first time to start autoplay from the second time on its own in iphone devices. Thank you.

```
<video src="a.mp4" id="video" frameborder="0" controls="" autoplay="" playsinline="" preload="auto"></video>
```

Comment: What do you mean by second time?

Comment: first time I have to click on play button as a gesture to play the video, but as I close the video and again try to load the video back it does not require  a gesture, it gets autoplayed

Comment: Did you pause that video on close?

Comment: Yes, I did pause the video on close

Comment: try removing the video element on closing video